# How to mask textbox with date format MM/yyyy using maskedit extender?

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net

I have one `TextBox` to enter Credit card date (only month & year ) in my asp.net application. I added the 'TextBox`with`masked edit extender`with`Mask="99/9999"`and`Mask Type="Date"`. But its not working , it works only when I give the format`'99/99/9999'`for`Mask` . Can any one know the solution for that?

Answer (score -1):

Its better to use Regular Expression, regular Expression give you more control over validation.

You can create you own validation rule in Regular Expression and then can validate text box.

You can learn more about regular expression on give link.

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/206330/Learning-REGEX-regular-expression-in-the-most-ea